# TFS 2010 - Is there any way to get my changes back after I have done "Undo Pending changes"?

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to get my changes that I made in local machine back after I have done "Undo Pending changes"?

I think it's not possible but still, i'm wondering if anyone knows a way..

Comment: I am just facing the same problem, how I regret!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the same number of ways you would have if you overwrote a regular file (so probably none but you might have had a backup script or something similar run on your machine).

Comment: Bad luck, unfortunately this is a case of: learned += new Lesson("Commit early and often");

Comment: yes.. used to commit early and often. but we are moving SVN to TFS and took a while to get new TFS up and running so didn't check the code for 4 days.. probably, i should setup auto-backup script on my machine..

Comment: Wow 4 days of lost work.. Best of luck - I just realised if it was a delete you could actually recover it, but I don't think there's any way to recover overwritten content unless you have a copy (e.g. from a backup script).

Answer (score 20):

If you have **not** built your project after the "Undo Pending changes" -

You can open the dll in Reflector and copy the correct code.

Comment: Great help! Thank you. This should be marked as an answer (in my view).

Comment: To info. You wont get commended out code back with this method.

Comment: Is a reflector a software?

Comment: @falsify - [yes.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector) Now there are also free tools like ILSpy.