# Is there any way to get my changes back after I have done "Undo Pending changes"

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Git.

I added a new file to the project (For example: Test.cs) and it was not committed to GitHub yet. What happens if I undo all my changes? Does VS delete my file? if so is there any ways to recover that deleted file?

I used a recovery tools that like Reflector and other tools but didn't help me.

This answers didn't help:

- [How can I get my changes back after clicking "Undo pending changes..." in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869918/how-can-i-get-my-changes-back-after-clicking-undo-pending-changes-in-visual)
- [TFS 2010 - Is there any way to get my changes back after I have done "Undo Pending changes"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146885/tfs-2010-is-there-any-way-to-get-my-changes-back-after-i-have-done-undo-pendi?lq=1)

Is there any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Undoing changes is pretty permanent as explained in the questions you link to. You might have some luck with filesystem recovery tools. If you want any chance at recovering the file, don't touch the machine anymore and download the recovery tools on another machine. - That's for TFS though. Git [may store some history on the file in the index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108853/recovering-added-file-after-doing-git-reset-hard-head).

Comment: if you can't use the methods in the questions you linked and you didn't keep any backups, then no. This is why you commit early and commit often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported option for recovering changes after undoing pending changes.  A file system recovery is likely your only option but is a long shot.